# Disconnect a laptop charger in software?

Tags: dell, laptop, power-management, battery

Short of the question: Are there any particular mechanisms to temporarily switch the charger input on a laptop on or off in software? In particular I am looking at a Dell Inspiron E1505 in my case.

Reason I bring this up is I currently have this laptop running as a makeshift server and it is on a UPS separate from its own battery. That UPS is operating my cable modem and other tertiary equipment. My problem is in the current state in a power outage the laptop will continue to pull power from the UPS before it even starts using its own battery. What would be nice would be when the UPS reports an outage to disconnect the charger and run off its internal battery and should for some reason the UPS outlast the internal battery, reconnect and go from there.

In the interim I could probably just plug the laptop in the non-backed up side of the UPS as it is 95% likely the internal battery will outlast the UPS but the above would be awesome if doable at all.